# How to add new lines of code to multiple classes when a new branch is created in github/gitlab/bitbucket?

Tags: java, maven, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I would like to automate a small process .

Lets assume that there is a master branch which has a maven project inside it.
and it has class A inside it and the code looks somewhat like the below

```
public class A {

private static final String FEATURE_VAL = "Old Feautre/task number";
private Static final String AUTHOR_VAL = "John Doe";

}
```

Now a task gets assigned to me and I create a branch from the master.
lets say the task number is #001 and the branch that I create is named as TEST:001
now inside the class A I want a new field to be added like so

```java
public class A {

private static final String FEATURE_VAL = "Old Feautre/task number";
private Static final String AUTHOR_VAL = "John Doe";

//new fields

private static final String FEATURE_VAL_NEW = "001 or anything";
private Static final String AUTHOR_VAL_NEW = "JOHN DOE";


}
```

is it possible to get it done?

Comment: First I would ask why you would like to change only based on the thing that a branch has been changed and it looks like a changelog or alike?

Comment: @khmarbaise , because currently everytime when a branch gets created i need to manually go and add new fields to the class A and lets say its a util class or like you mentioned a changelog class
And based on the values/fields available in the Classs A ,I can do my data manipulation.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: What do you mean by adding manually fields... ? For what purpose to solve issues/feature requests ? In particular because those files are private? You are using a version control system which shows the changes over the time...manually recording changes it useless nor needed...and not helpful.

Comment: I also do not understand the purpose of those private fields.

Comment: Its for the Feature Toggles.
when I create a new branch I want to automate a way to create a new Toggle .
and if the toggle is on then it will go to my code and if its off then it will go to the old code.
and class A has list of all the toggles and their names.

Comment: My bad!! lets assume those are public fields.

Comment: If it's done automatically how will it be removed? This will pile up the feature toggles...Also I would really reconsider a way via a Java class file might be not the best way..why not using a property file?

Comment: ok, it completely skipped my mind, yes, it will be better to use the property file than adding it to the class. Thank you .